# Checkstyle errors while using Lombok

Tags: java, checkstyle, lombok

While compiling following class which uses Lombok for auto generating getters and setters, Checkstyle throws a compilation error:

> Utility classes should not have a public or default constructor

```
@Getter
@Setter
public class foo {
    private String type;
    private int value;
}
```

Why does Checkstyle classify the above class as utility class, when it does not follow the utility class definition as specified in [checkstyle's documentation](http://checkstyle.sourceforge.net/config_design.html#HideUtilityClassConstructor)? i.e. classes containing only static methods or fields.
Is checkstyle parsing the default source text file or the lombok generated source file?

Comment: checkstyle just parse java file, Please report an issue to https://github.com/checkstyle/checkstyle/issues , please provide compilable source file(you can fake annotation in the same file) and reproduce issue by cli - http://checkstyle.sourceforge.net/cmdline.html#Download_and_Run

Answer (score 17):

Checkstyle works on the source code, it doesn't see that lombok will generate bytecode so it sees a class that has only two private fields it assumes you have an utility class.
An utility class should have a `private` constructor in case of that checkstyle, but you probably don't want that (you wouldn't be able to create instance of this class), so what you need is either remove `HideUtilityClassConstructor` from list of checkstyle rules, or add (see http://checkstyle.sourceforge.net/config_annotation.html#SuppressWarnings#SuppressWarningsHolder) `@SuppressWarnings("checkstyle:HideUtilityClassConstructor")`:

```
@Getter
@Setter
@SuppressWarnings("checkstyle:HideUtilityClassConstructor")
public class foo {
    private String type;
    private int value;
}
```

Comment: I would not recommend to use this way. Since you'll require to annotate each class. The shown solution here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63791277/3880225 is using a global config for defining this on any lombok annotated class. The suppression is done on the complete classpath and thus defines it once for any future and past implemented class.

Answer (score 8):

with checkstyle there is a nice ***XPathSuppressionFilter***. To use it

add to your checkstyle.xml file

```
  <!-- externalize the ignored/suppressed checks -->
  <module name="SuppressionFilter">
     <property name="file" value="./checkstyle-suppressions.xml" />
     <property name="optional" value="false" />
  </module>
```

and in checkstyle-suppressions.xml

```
<!-- disable checks against lombok annotations -->
<suppress-xpath checks="HideUtilityClassConstructor" query="//CLASS_DEF[.//ANNOTATION/IDENT[@text='UtilityClass']]"/>
<suppress-xpath checks="HideUtilityClassConstructor" query="//CLASS_DEF[.//ANNOTATION/IDENT[@text='Getter']]"/>
<suppress-xpath checks="HideUtilityClassConstructor" query="//CLASS_DEF[.//ANNOTATION/IDENT[@text='Setter']]"/>
```

Answer (score 6):

If annotations does not work for you, (due to checkstyle version you're using), you can use

```
// CHECKSTYLE:SUPPRESS:HideUtilityClassConstructor
@Getter
@Setter
public class Foo {
    private String type;
    private int value;
}
// CHECKSTYLE:UNSUPPRESS:HideUtilityClassConstructor
```

instead.